# activate php form with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is the code. Man I'm sending this to my online server e-mail and the php form server is not working! The email never arrive! Anyone knows why it not working correctly?

`

Enter some text in the fields below, then press the "Submit form" button to submit the form.

name: 
  tel:  
  mail: 
  


function myFunction() {

  document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

}

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$tel      = $_POST['tel'];
$mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];


$subject  = "Solicitação de cotação recebida por ".$name;
$message  = "hello ".$tel;

$headers  = "Email: " .$mailFrom;
$txt      = "Você recebeu uma solicitação de cotação recebida por ".$name.".\n\n".$message;

$mailTo1   = 'marketing@macbrs.com.br';

mail($mailTo1,  $subject, $txt, $headers);

header("Location: action_page.php?mailsend");

}
?>
```

`

I want a code that makes connection with php and javascript
to natural server and gmail!
looks like this -

name
title

button onclick calltoaction

function calltoaction

activate php

php post data

name
title

send to mail!

if anyone can help!

Simple solutions man! Plz!

Answer (score 0):

Beware there is certainly no `$_POST['submit']` value, so the first test fails and nothing is done.

If you test the following in a `test.php` file :

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
 <p>Your name : <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p>Your age : <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" value="OK"></p>
</form>
```

First call gives :

[image]

And when I fill and submit my form :

[image]

So, nothing about `submit` is received by the server.

---

EDIT

---

One more point : you can't assume that all the values are set, so your test could look like :

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['tel']) && isset($_POST['mail'])){
  // do what you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Philippe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69592392/11041841) said, there is no `$_POST['submit']`.

Simply set the if as so:

```php
if ($_POST) {
```

This checks if the `$_POST` has any value, so it comes in handy.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the mention. I would point out that testing `$_POST` is not enough, as you can't assume that all the values are set. So you must test all the keys with `isset`. The OP would face this issue too.

Comment: You are sure right! every input should be checked and validated.